# bash stdout output appearing in redirected stderr file

Tags: linux, bash, redirect, echo, stderr

Bash docs say that `echo` writes to `stdout`. I have a script that redirects `stderr` to a file with `2>/home/pi/mydir/stderr-log.txt`. It doesn't redirect `stdout`. Yet text output by `echo` is going into the log file.

Could it make any difference that the script is being run in the background (by adding `&` to the end of the command)?

The complete script:

```
#! /bin/sh

case "$1" in 
start)
echo "Starting mjpg_streamer!"
#First init
/usr/local/bin/mjpg_streamer -i "/usr/local/lib/mjpg-streamer/input_uvc.so -n -f 30 -r 640x480 -d /dev/video0" -o "/usr/local/lib/mjpg-streamer/output_http.so -p 8085 -w /usr/local/share/mjpg-streamer/www" 2>/home/pi/mydir/stderr-log.txt &
#Second init
/usr/local/bin/mjpg_streamer -i "/usr/local/lib/mjpg-streamer/input_uvc.so -n -f 30 -r 640x480 -d /dev/video1" -o "/usr/local/lib/mjpg-streamer/output_http.so -p 8086 -w /usr/local/share/mjpg-streamer/www" 2>/home/pi/mydir/stderr-log.txt &
;;
stop)
echo "Stopping mjpg_streamer!"
killall mjpg_streamer
;;
*)
echo "usage: videoinit {start|stop}"
exit 1
;;
esac
exit 0
```

The script that calls this script (when it finds a new error message in the log file):

```
#!/bin/bash

    ERRORLOG="/home/pi/mydir/stderr-log.txt"
    LINECOUNT=0
    NEWLINECOUNT=0
    rm ${ERRORLOG}
    touch ${ERRORLOG}
    while true; do
       inotifywait -q -e modify ${ERRORLOG} > /dev/null
       NEWLINECOUNT=$(grep --count "Error grabbing frames" ${ERRORLOG} )
       if [[ NEWLINECOUNT > LINECOUNT ]]; then
          LINECOUNT=NEWLINECOUNT
          /etc/init.d/videoinit stop
          echo "Attempting mjpg-streamer reboot."
          /etc/init.d/videoinit start
       fi
    done
```

Comment: No, backgrounding it would not make any difference.

Comment: Is is possible to do something like `1>stdout` to force the echo output to the Terminal?

Comment: There's no way to force it as such, but you can make it happen depending on the reason why/if it's going into the file in the first place. If you want to figure out why, you can post the code you run, how you run it, and how you tell that it's not doing what you want (preferably as a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: Perhaps you have `exec >&2` or something like it in your script?

Comment: complete script is posted

Comment: Not in that script, but the script that runs *it*.

Comment: added the script that calls this one

Comment: @RobertLewis You can try `echo ... > /dev/tty`

Comment: Can you confirm that you're calling the second script directly from the terminal, and it shows "Attempting mjpg-streamer reboot" on screen. However, it does not show "Starting mjpg_streamer" on screen at any time. Then when you open /home/pi/mydir/stderr-log.txt in an editor in a second terminal, you see the line "Starting mjpg_streamer"?